# How to start two Docker containers nginx locally

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, localhost, docker-machine

I am trying to start with with `docker-compose up -d` two docker containers, but it starts only one, I need to start other too. Is there any way to do that in localhost, or if I can start in on other port, how to do that?

First project nginx:

```
 nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST:-./}:/var/www/html
      - .docker/nginx/default:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./localhost.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt
      - ./localhost.key:/etc/ssl/private/localhost.key
    ports:
      - "${HOST_HTTP_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Second project:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST:-./}:/var/www/html
      - .docker/nginx/default:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./localhost.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt
      - ./localhost.key:/etc/ssl/private/localhost.key
    ports:
      - "${HOST_HTTP_PORT:-8080}:80"
      - "4430:443"
      - "2022:2022"
    depends_on:
      - laraphp-fpm
    networks:
      - proxynet
```

**UPDATE:
I solved just adding in second project .env `HOST_HTTP_PORT=90`, and now one is on port 80, and second on 90. It works.**

Comment: Please edit your post and add your docker-compose.yml file to the post

Comment: I added this nginx part

Comment: After `docker-compose up` can you do a `docker ps -a` and see if you can see the failed nginx container? If you can find it, then do `docker logs <container name>` to see the log.

Comment: Can you combine these two Compose files into one?  Are they in the same directory; or if not, do the two directories have the same name?

Comment: Hi, I can't combine, because those are two different projects, they are in same directory, and they don't have the same name